# Django manager in lookup fields

Tags: django, django-managers, django-model-utils

I have a SoftDeletableModel named Offer:

```
class Offer(SoftDeletableModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='offers')
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='offers')
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I am using below query to get all Orders that current user has an offer in it.

```
Order.objects.filter(offers__user=request.user)
```

but it counts deleted offers in lookup query.
for example, if a user delete his offer from an order, this query returns that order too.

an other example is something like this: `Order.objects.filter(offers=48)`. offer 48 is removed but i get result from this query too.

does django use default manger for lookup fields?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
Order.objects.filter(offers__user=request.user, is_deleted=False)
```